# Fortran: Type containing a member that is an array of elements of this type

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran

I need to declare a type a, containing a member that is an array of elements of type a.

I am thinking about something like:

```
type:: a
type(pta), dimension(:), allocatable:: array
end type a

type:: pta
class(a), pointer:: p
end type pta
```

What is the right way to do that in Fortran ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply insert a pointer in your type. This would look like:

```
type a
  type(a), dimension(:), pointer :: array
end type
```

You can then simply allocate the array in its desired size.

Answer (score 4):

Or get yourself a Fortran 2008 compiler and you can write

```
type :: a
  type(a), dimension(:), allocatable :: array
end type
```

While appreciating the rep garnered by the original form of this answer I should point out that, as far as I know, only the IBM and Cray Fortran compilers currently support this feature of the emerging standard.  @Stefan's answer is implementable on all the current crop of widely used Fortran compilers.